# Generate new password for users periodically and notify user of new password

Tags: 7, users

I am running a private Drupal 7 site where all user accounts are created by admins and managers. I need to ensure that all users have access to the email account that their accounts were created with.

**What is the best way to do the following:**

- Create a user account with an automatically generated password, and notify the new user of their password via email.
- After a 4 week period, a new password must be generated for the user and set as their active password automatically. The user needs to be notified of their newly updated password via email, and the newly generated password must be used to access the site until it is reset again.

Are there any Drupal 7 modules that can help achieve this?

Any suggestions on building a custom module that can help resolve this?

Comment: Hate to be "that guy"...but if you're planning to send the password out over email, you'll never be ensuring anything. Far too easy to intercept

Comment: In many jurisdictions your plan is outright illegal. In some others, if you mail users' passwords you can't keep them responsible for anything they do - but they can hold *you* responsible for actions made using their accounts. What you plan to do is to **give away their passwords on regular basis**. You will be giving it to mailserver admins (both your and theirs), and potentially to anyone in the same open WiFi at coffe point your clients are. Not to mention anyone who can take a look at their screen over their shoulder. Are you damn sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: I don't mind "that guy" when he makes a lot of sense. What if its a one time login link instead of the actual password? The user is required to change their password imminently after log in through the link.

Comment: @user1732920 one-time login link is usually legal. But aren't you afraid it'll be a nuisance for your users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue was talked about during the great Drupalgeddon. Because no such bulk reset tool existed for a site.

Here is a recently created tool to perform this task. Other such tools have existed since Drupalgeddon.

[Mass Password Reset Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/mass_pwreset)

> This module allows users with "Administer users" permission to reset
>   all user accounts and notify all users
>
> **Details**
>
> The module will reset the passwords of all users except the
>   administrative superuser id 1. You can optionally reset the
>   administrative superuser id 1. Once passwords have been reset, users
>   will optionally receive emails using the Drupal password recovery
>   email. The password recovery email content can be edited at the
>   account settings configuration page.
>
> **Use Cases**
>
> You have a large number of user accounts pre-created and
>   want to send password recovery emails to all users during a site
>   launch. You need to quickly change all passwords on a site for
>   security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Force Password Change](https://www.drupal.org/project/force_password_change) module too. Read the description:

> This module allows administrators to force users, by role, individual
>   user, or newly created user, to change their password on their next
>   page load or login, and/or expire their passwords after a period of
>   time.

Comment: Interesting module suggestion, didn't know about this one yet (there are only 17K module, right?). Any idea how to "notify" the user(s) with this module (as in the question)? Or maybe something you could do in combintion with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module somehow?